# WCF publish in IIS - can not get wsdl definition

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, iis-10

I am using IIS 10 and Visual studio 2019. OS: windows 10

I have just created basic wcf web site (WCF Service Application). It's very simple, just a basic example.

I have tried to run this project in debug mode, with IIS express, running WcfTestClient. All good, wsdl is consumed from the link:  http://localhost:62549/Service1.svc?wsdl

But, I need to publish this service to IIS. So, I've done publish with configuration:

[image]

All good, I see newly created application inside IIS.

But now, I can not get wsdl definition. Link: http://localhost/WcfService4/Service1.svc?wsdl

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Interface:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WcfService4
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
    }
}
```

Class:

```
namespace WcfService4
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfService4.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    </system.web>



    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior" name="WcfService4.Service1">
                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="basicHttpBinding"
                          contract="WcfService4.IService1" />
                <endpoint address="mex"
                          binding="mexHttpBinding"
                          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>

        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error is that http activation is off in the windows features, you can turn it on in control->programs and features, select “Turn Windows features on or off”, then turn HTTP Activation on in your .net framework version advanced service.

[image]